# How to create a xUnit test case for await _propertyRepository.UnitOfWork.SaveEntitiesAsync()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, microservices

How can I test `return await _propertyRepository.UnitOfWork.SaveEntitiesAsync();`?

## AddCommandHandler

```
public async Task<bool> Handle(AddCommand message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{

    _logger.LogInformation("----- Adding Property - Property: {@Property}", property);

    _propertyRepository.Add(property);

    return await _propertyRepository.UnitOfWork.SaveEntitiesAsync();
}
```

Anyone please guide me to write test case for that only. I am writing like this. But the test case fails.

## PropertyRepository

```
public class PropertyRepository : IPropertyRepository
    {
        private readonly RealxContext _realxContext;

        public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork
        {
            get
            {
                return _realxContext;
            }
        }

        public PropertyRepository(RealxContext realxContext)
        {
            _realxContext = realxContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(realxContext));

        }
```

## AddCommandHandlerTests.cs

```
_propertyRepository.Setup(propertyRepo => propertyRepo.UnitOfWork.SaveEntitiesAsync(default(CancellationToken))).Returns(Task.FromResult(true));
```

Comment: you need to mock the UnitOfWork Property with a mocked DBContext. Then need to setup() the SaveEntitiesAsync() on that mocked DBContext

Comment: like this   _unitofwork.Setup(x => x.SaveEntitiesAsync(default(CancellationToken)));  ?

Comment: still i was confused. send me a anyexample if anyone have related this. ?